# Alternative to 'GO' for batch in potential stored procedure (temp tables used)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have a wall of code I want to turn into a SP. It begins with the bulk insert of a pretty messy .CSV into a temp table, and requires tons of UPDATEs and ALTERs. There's actually a few temp tables used further down in the code, too.

I was using GO for batching all of these, but now that I want to turn it into a SP can't really do that anymore. Naturally if I remove the all of the GO's, I'll get 'Invalid column name' errors on the temp tables as they no longer run in order. Wondering what my alternatives are?

Sample pre-Create Procedure code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Map', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Map
GO

CREATE TABLE #Map
    (
        RowNum NVARCHAR(255)
        , Entity_Type NVARCHAR(255)
        , Tagging_Status NVARCHAR(255)
        , Website NVARCHAR(255)
        , Mock_Pages_Viewed NVARCHAR(255)
    )
GO

BULK INSERT #Map
FROM '\\*Server*\*Folder*\*SubFolder*\*File*.csv'
WITH
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
        , ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
        , FIRSTROW = 3
    )
GO

ALTER TABLE #Map
DROP COLUMN RowNum
GO

ALTER TABLE #Map
DROP COLUMN Entity_Type
GO

UPDATE #Map
SET Mock_Pages_Viewed = SUBSTRING(Mock_Pages_Viewed, 2, LEN(Mock_Pages_Viewed)-2)
GO
```

Etc Etc

Comment: what is the reason for dropping column from the temp table ? if you don't need it, you can just ignore it

Comment: Honestly, if the code is particularly complicated, it might be worth your time to create permanent working tables to replace the temp tables, then break the code down into multiple procedures that execute sequentially. It'll take longer this week, but down the road when you need to alter a piece of the logic, or when the process breaks part way through at 3AM, you'll be ever so much happier to have the logical steps compartmentalized.

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables work a little differently in stored procedures.  You don't need to drop the temp table, as they are automatically dropped at the end of the procedure.   What you've got there should work fine.  If you need to, you can access the temp table in a nested batch using dynamic SQL.  EG:

```
create or alter procedure foo 
as
begin

    CREATE TABLE #Map
        (
            RowNum NVARCHAR(255)
            , Entity_Type NVARCHAR(255)
            , Tagging_Status NVARCHAR(255)
            , Website NVARCHAR(255)
            , Mock_Pages_Viewed NVARCHAR(255)
        )

    --BULK INSERT #Map
    --FROM '\\*Server*\*Folder*\*SubFolder*\*File*.csv'
    --WITH
    --  (
    --      FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
    --      , ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
    --      , FIRSTROW = 3
    --  )

    ALTER TABLE #Map
    DROP COLUMN RowNum

    ALTER TABLE #Map
    DROP COLUMN Entity_Type

    UPDATE #Map
    SET Mock_Pages_Viewed = SUBSTRING(Mock_Pages_Viewed, 2, LEN(Mock_Pages_Viewed)-2)

    exec ('alter table #map drop column Mock_Pages_Viewed')

    select * 
    from #map

end
```

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure runs within the context of a single batch. GO is just a batch separator, and you cannot have multiple batches within a stored procedure, unless you revert to creating SQL strings and executing them for each batch within the stored procedure. That's almost always a poor idea.

Far better will be to rewrite the procedure code so that it can all run without a batch separator.

Also, rather than all the fiddling around with the temp tables, consider using OPENROWSET instead of BULK INSERT. Then you can just treat the external data like a table, and you can just select the columns you want and filter the rows you want. That would avoid all the dropping columns part, etc.